# git merge leaves a mess if "permission denied" for writing one file

Tags: git

Scenario:

- I have a repository, possibly with some untracked local modifications.
- I do a `git merge somebranch`, which should modify ~100 files or more, but leave the local modifications as they are.
- One of the files is not writable or removable due to poorly set up permissions.

Result:

- git merge fails, saying e.g. "unable to unlink old 'sites/default/default.settings.php' (Permission denied)"
- all the modifications for the other 99 files are now unstaged, all new files untracked. So `git status` now gives me a long list of untracked local modifications.

If I had some untracked modifications before the attempted merge, the disaster is now complete, because I can no longer distinguish what was modified before, and what is new thanks to the merge.

My questions would be:

- Why does git merge leave a mess, if it cannot write or delete a file?
- Could I have avoided this?
- How can I get back to a "safe" state?

Answer (score 0):

My own solution so far is this:

```
git add .
git stash
chmod u+rw path/to/problematic/directory
git merge somebranch
git stash apply
git status
```

The `git status` shows if any local modifications are left. These should be the ones you had before the merge.

Afterwards you might want to `git stash drop` for clean-up.

This does not answer all questions, but it was good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem when i executed **git merge anotherBranch** command in VS Code Editor. When I restarted the Editor, the "Permission Denied" Error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically stash and reapply changes:

```
git merge BRANCH --autostash
```